# Why does ArrayList.set() leave a method without any exception?

Tags: java, android, exception, android-emulator

I am currently hung with a problem when developing on my Android virtual machine (emulator, Android 2.1). It's not so much about solving the problem but about understanding. What I have is this method:

```
private void storeData(int crmValue, int crmTouch, int heartrate) {
    // Store in data or ring buffer
    waitCRM.add(crmValue);
    waitTouch.add(crmTouch);
    waitHeart.add(heartrate);
}
```

wait*** are instance variables of the user-defined class RingBuffer. The add method of this class goes like this:

```
public void add(E o) {
    buffer.set(index, o);
    index++;
    if (index == capacity) {
        index = 0;
    }
    if (length < capacity) {
        length++;
    }
}
```

E in this case is an Integer, the buffer is an ArrayList, the capacity is 60 and the index is 0 because this is the first add() call.

Of course the ArrayList/buffer is empty at this point and buffer.set() may be incorrect, because this would return the current value. Actually buffer.add() does not solve the problem, but that is only a details to solve. Shouldn't bother you for now.

The storeData() method is called in a ScheduledFuture (a timer) each 100 ms (atFixedRate). As long as the timer won't call storeData() due to an IF everything works as expected. But as soon as storeData() is called for the first time...

... the program leaves the method storeData() during waitCRM.add(crmValue);

... the timer is cancelled (other threads resume working)

... and no exception or anything else is found in the Console or the LogCat

Given no error message it cost me hours just to find out so much. So here is my question: How and under what circumstances will Java/Android stop a thread withoud showing any error?

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks like you are getting an exception in `add(E o)`, which for some reason you don't see in the logcat.

The method set() is wrong, if you look in the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int, java.lang.Object)

> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.
>
> Throws:
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if index out of range (index < 0 || index >= size()).

So with set you should be getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException because you don't have any elements yet, index == 0, size == 0 and index >= size == true

But add(int index, Object element) should work, and you say you get the same problem...

Put a log or breakpoint in your code in your add method and see at which line it exits.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I already had mentioned the set() problem in the question. Using an add() does not change the behavior. I went through the methods step by step and when reaching the buffer.add(index, o) the debugger just resumes after my "step into", cancelling the timer. The set() does not throw an exception either, so I still don't understand *why* I do not see any error at all...

Comment: i currently don't have an explanation why you are not seeing an error, are you sure your buffer is not null and index is 0 at that point? have you examined them when the debugger stops in that line?

Comment: might it be that the debugger jumps to the main thread when the error ocurrs and you don't see it because of that... can't you change the thread in the debugger?... also check the logcat for warnings or system.out.println messages, maybe there's something you're missing.

Comment: you probably are catching some kinds of exceptions when starting the timer... if you don't do anything in the catch block, you will not see the error message. put `exception.printStackTrace()` in your catch blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Of course I have checked all the LogCat for any hints - I did not found any. The buffer is correctly initialized (according to the code and th debug information) and the index is 0. The catch sounds like a good hint - but there is no catch "around" this part of the code at all. Strange thing.

Comment: @lxx: Very good idea - however the debugger says I am still in the same thread. But walking the code step by step I am somewhere completely different at once (somewhere in the FutureTask java internal sources...). Before posting the timer management, I must confirm that I suffer the same problem at a completely different position in code. Thanks so far!

Comment: Is seems that the problem was somewhere completely different. I use the apache StringUtils. I am still not sure if this information from the LogCat is the key - but when replacing the StringUtils.join() by a hand-made method, this solves the crash. Actually I still do not understand why I do not get any more feedback in the debugger... So an answer is still very welcome. LogCat: W/dalvikvm(1302): VFY: unable to resolve static method 373: Lorg/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils;.join (Ljava/lang/Iterable;C)Ljava/lang/String;